# Android - Keep Service Running to keep Data in Storage

Tags: android, caching, memory, service, storage

İ have  an Android App, with a Widget, which accesses Data from Storage. The Data is cached in Memory during App runtime, but when it comes to the widget, it always has to access Fata from storage, not from Memory, because the Application properly stops.

Because the Application completely finishes and will be restarted, each time some calculations are done and alarms are set.

The widgets are updated each Minute (when screen is on), because it shows the time. This from time to time causes some battery drain, which I am trying to prevent.

I am thinking of keeping a service running, only to keep the Memory cache and alarms alive?

Is this a good idea? Or does anybody have a better idea?

Thank you in advance...

Answer (score 0):

If you want to store data when the app is not active, just store the data. Android has a SQLite database for that purpose. I use ORMLite, which makes it easier to store Java objects in the Android SQLite database. For the alarms, you could use [AlarmManager](http://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms.html). I don't think a Service is the best way to store data or manage alarms.